# Why is this not a pronoun error? "To those of us who had heard the principal [..] the news of the staff cuts was not surprising."

Tags: pronouns, past-perfect, verb-agreement

From the SAT:

> To those of us who **had heard** the principal of the high school talk about the budget, the news of the staff cuts **was** not surprising.

Why is it **had** and not **have**? Because isn't **those** plural?

Comment: **had heard** is cast in the Past Perfect tense, to make it "deeper in the past" compared to the Simple Past construction "*was not surprising*". There is no plural-singular distinction for the **had** verb in Past Perfect.

Comment: 'those' is plural but who said that plurals don't take 'had'? Is it this bothering you?

Comment: I didn't make the link that it is a past perfect tense. I just looked at the verb and the subject and nothing else which is not good.

Comment: Even just looking at the verb "to have" by itself, the 3rd person singular present tense form is "has," the present tense form for all other persons and numbers is "have," and there is only one past tense form for all persons and numbers: "had."

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Had heard** is cast in the Past Perfect tense, to make it "deeper in the past" compared with the Simple Past construction "*was not surprising*". There is no plural-singular distinction for the **had** verb in Past Perfect.

Compare:

> "To those of us who **have heard** the principal the news **seems** grim", said John.

From the standpoint of John, the time when he spoke was present. This is why John used the Present Perfect construction **have heard**, and since **those** is plural, he used **have**.

> John said that to those of them who **had heard** the principal the news **seemed** grim.

Now we are reporting what John said. We backshift **seem** to **seemed** (Simple Past), and backshift **have heard** even deeper in the past, making it **had heard** (Past Perfect).

Answer (score 7):

You seem to be confused about the applicability of the past tense verb form "had" (and, by extension, the past perfect "had heard") to plural subjects.  While the present tense form "have" does have a separate form "has" for third-person singular subjects, no such separate form exists for "had":

> **Present perfect:**
>
> - I **have** heard.
> - You **have** heard.
> - He/she **has** heard. (← distinct third person singular form)
> - We **have** heard.
> - You **have** heard.
> - They **have** heard.

> **Past perfect:**
>
> - I **had** heard.
> - You **had** heard.
> - He/she **had** heard.
> - We **had** heard.
> - You **had** heard.
> - They **had** heard.

This is actually a general feature of English verb morphology, not just something peculiar to the verb "have".  Compare e.g. "I walk", "he/she walk**s**", "they walk" in the present tense, but "I walked", "he/she walked", "they walked" in the past tense.

Ps. In your question, you've also emphasized the singular third-person verb "was", whose subject in the sentence is "the news".  The reason for *that* apparent concordance failure is that, despite looking like a plural (and, historically, originally being one), the word "[news](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/news)" in modern English is [uncountable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_noun)* (just like "water" or "information" or "happiness") and thus takes singular verb forms.  So:

> - OK: The news **is** good.
> - Wrong: <s>The news **are** good.</s> ("News" is not plural.)

And also:

> - OK: I've heard news from home.
> - OK: I've heard **some** news from home.
> - Wrong: <s>I've heard **a** news from home.</s> ("News" takes no indefinite article.)

<sub>*) The Wiktionary page I linked to above does list the rare plural form "[newses](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/newses)" for "news".  While it's not really surprising that such a plural should exist (as pretty much all "uncountable" English nouns *can* be pluralized in special situations, e.g. when referring to multiple distinct collections of the uncountable substance), in my personal experience I must say that it is *very* rare, and not something you should normally use.  Even when speaking of multiple distinct items or sets of news (as in "today's and yesterday's news"), the word "news" still normally remains uncountable, and still takes singular verb forms.</sub>

Comment: I'd certainly recommend 'pieces of news' instead of 'newses'. Heck, the spellchecker even thinks 'newses' is wrong!

Comment: @Ϻ.Λ.Ʀ. Indeed. Wiktionary does give a few quotations to support its existence, but frankly, in two out of the three examples given, I'd personally consider it wrong and would just use "news". The remaining quote speaks of "*125 USA Todays, 250 to 300 Wall Street Journals, 300 to 350 **Daily Newses**, 550 to 600 New York Timeses, and 4,500 to 5,000 New York Posts*", which I suppose is valid, even if I'd probably have tried to find some other way to phrase it (e.g. using "copies of").

Answer (score 5):

We may reasonably infer that the context here establishes a'Reference Time' —the time that is being talked about—as the time when the cuts were announced.

At that time, the cuts were surprising to most people, but not to those people who had heard the principal speak about the budget *at some earlier time*.

*Had heard* is a past perfect: the event it names is one which occurred **before** Reference Time and gives rise to a state **at** Reference Time: in this case, a state of 'non-surprise'.

*Have* does not inflect for number in its past-tense form; *had* is used with all numbers and persons.